# AWS Lambda [Node.js 4.3] - Strange Stack Trace

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

We are writing `AWS` lambda functions with `node.js 4.3`, but we encoutered a strange `behaviour` with throwing an error.

First:

```js
'use strict'; 
   
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    throw new Error();
};
```

This is throwing like expected:

```
 at exports.handler (/var/task/TestCode.js:4:11)
```

But if we a add a function (even uncalled), which calls a function of a different class/obj, which contains a lambda expression with an obj, we get a mysterious throwing info. 
To make the things a bit more understandable, here some code:

```js
'use strict';

function aRandomFunction() {
    something.foo((obj) => {});
}
    
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    throw new Error();
};
```

Now we get an log we do not understand why:

```
 at something.foo.exports.handler (/var/task/TestCode.js:8:11)
```

Can someone explain me why that happens? It seems to be some `JS` magic I do not understand :)

Thanks

Comment: What else is in the stack trace?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That is all. Only Error at [see code above]. But that is normal in an aws lambda.

Answer (score 1):

## Revised Answer - Upgrade to v6.1

Your issue is the Node version 4.3.  Upgrading to 6.1 will resolve the issue.

I re-created the code snippet you provided and ran it in both environments.  The following errors were given for both cases respectively.

- 4.3

  - `at something.foo.module.exports.test (/var/task/handler.js:56:10)`
  - Unexpected result.
- 6.1

  - `at module.exports.test (/var/task/handler.js:56:10)`
  - This would be the expected result given the throw.

## Original Answer - polyfill

Your issue is your arrow function on the line referenced in the error message...

```js
'use strict';

function aRandomFunction() {
    something.foo((obj) => {});  // illegal arrow function (ES6 not supported in Lambda environment by default)
}

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    throw new Error();
};
```

ES6 is not supported by Lambda node environments without a polyfill - even tho it is supported in ^4.0 in traditional Node environments.  This is due to the fact that AWS Lambda does not use a complete and up to date Node engine code base.  It was originally designed for smaller use cases (e.g. Alexa skill sets & single function calls) so "extra" features were axed - most of ES6 being one of the victims.

For the polyfill, I recommend babel.

Solution:

1. Install the relevant babel packages. (see package.json for reference)
2. Add the following line to the top of your `handler.js` - should do the
   trick.

```js
'use strict';
if (!global._babelPolyfill) require('babel-polyfill');  // insert polyfill assignment

function aRandomFunction() {
    something.foo((obj) => {});
}

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    throw new Error();
};
```

```js
// package.json (not a valid comment)
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "serverless-webpack": "^1.0.0-rc.4",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  }
```

And if you're using a framework like **Serverless**, then here's `webpack.config.js`, and the `serverless.yml`

```js
// webpack.config.js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: './handler.js',
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',  // add babel-loader
      include: __dirname,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader',
    }],
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
};
```

```js
  # serverless.yml
  service: myApp

  package:
    exclude:

  provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs4.3
    stage: development
    region: ap-northeast-1

  plugins:
    - serverless-webpack

  custom:
    webpackIncludeModules: true
    main:
      babelOptions:                         # include babel options
        presets: [es2015, es2016, stage-0]
        plugins: [transform-runtime]

  functions:
    main:
      handler: handler.main
      memorySize: 1024
      timeout: 10
      events:
        - http:
```

Comment: Aha, so this should work as written if using Lambda's Node 6.10, then, rather than 4.3?

Comment: @tobiah It is NOT true that ES6 is not supported on Lambda. There is partial support for ES6 (More info at [node.green](http://node.green/). Arrow functions ARE supported in Node 4.3. You don't need `babel`, `webpack`, and `serverless-webpack` just for the arrow function.

Comment: @dashmug - It's a well known fact for avid Lambda users that AWS' Node environment whether it's v6 or v4 doesn't run an up to date engine due to the fact that at it's inception design, Lambda wasn't considered to be used as an entire backend but only for micro services (e.g. Alexa skill sets) so there was a refactor of the native Node code base to optimize for smaller function use cases.  So ES6 support was considered verbose and axed.  There's many articles documenting this fact.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  I run V6 in all my Lambda apps and ES6 is not supported by default. You need the polyfill.

Comment: @TobiahRex Do you have a reference on what is supported or not? I have some lambdas using _some_ ES6 features like arrow functions without `babel` and many have been running with no problems for more than a year now. I know full ES6 is not supported but I am certain some ES6 features are (like arrow functions).

Comment: @TobiahRex I also used ES6 classes heavily by the way in my NodeJS 4.3 and v6.10 lambdas. No `babel`. No `serverless-webpack`. I only use `serverless-webpack` for my Typescript project on Lambda.

Comment: @dashmug lol that's pretty funny cuz ive had the exact OPPOSITE experience. You have a repo I could check out? I'm currently looking for my bookmark articles as u requested...

Comment: @TobiahRex What's funny? I'm serious. I need to know where you got that info that Lambda has 0% support for ES6. If my lambda functions continue to work when they are not supposed to, that's scary for me. So I need to know.

Comment: @TobiahRex Here's a Lambda sample from AWS devs themselves: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-auth-reference-app/blob/master/api/lambda/errors.js (It uses ES6 classes). Here's another from `serverless`: https://github.com/serverless/serverless-starter/blob/master/lib/index.js (It uses arrow functions).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Are you using serverless to deploy this Lambda function?

I found this blog article supporting statement that ES6 is supported in AWS Lambdas by default : [here](https://github.com/TobiahRex/stack-overflow-qNa/tree/master/aws-lambda-es6-error)

Comment: @dashmug Ah!  I think i see why we're confessing different experiences.  First off thanks for the reply and references.  

If you notice in [single.js](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-starter/blob/master/single.js) there is no ES6 - since its the module directly referenced by serverles.yml.  The `var lib = require('./lib')` appears to be a layer of abstraction allowing ES6 syntax in those required modules but not in the module referenced by serverless.yml.  Could this be the where our different experiences are coming from?

Comment: @TobiahRex No. Try to create a new function in your AWS Console and use the provided "Hello World" blueprint. The "Hello World" blueprint itself uses arrow functions!

Comment: @TobiahRex So now you see an article that contradicts yourself!

Comment: @dashmug lol - I would agree i should not have said ALL ES6 is unsupported.  I should have said some of ES6 is not support.  ES6 Import/Export modules is 1 of many features that are not supported without a polyfill.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I tried to replicate your error in a Node4.3 environment with the snippets you provided and alas i got the same error.  Upgrading to Node6.1 moves the error down to the expected location where you explicitly throw your own Error. So to answer your question - YES upgrading to 6.1 will work. - i'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @TobiahRex All good. As I said earlier, http://node.green/ is a good reference to see which ES2015+ features are available in each Node version. Also, avid Lambda developers know that Lambda supports Node v6.10 not v6.1. Also, michal-sqlbot is not the OP and has 56k reputation.